# How can I echo both runnable commands and control-sequences to a named-pipe?

Tags: pipe, escape-characters, fifo

I have a named-pipe:

```
> ls -l
total 0
prw-r--r--  1 ivan  staff  0 Aug 24 08:32 fifo
```

In one terminal, I read from it in an infinite loop:

```
> while true; do sh -c "$(cat fifo)"; done
█
```

In another, I write runnable commands to the pipe:

```
> echo 'rspec path/to/example_spec.rb' > fifo
```

My first terminal runs the command:

```
> while true; do sh -c "$(cat fifo)"; done
.........

Finished in 0.00194 seconds (files took 0.10327 seconds to load)
9 examples, 0 failures

█
```

Now I'd like to send a control sequence to change the cursor shape from `█` to `_`. In the second terminal, I run:

```
> printf '\e[4 q' > fifo
```

But the reading terminal reports a garbled error (note the missing "c" in "command"):

```
sh: ommand not found
```

I tried `\e`, `\033`, `^[`, and `x1B` but all to no avail. I also tried using `echo`, but I'm on OSX, and BSD echo has no `-e` option.

How can I send the control-sequence properly escaped?

Comment: You're sending a control character, but you're executing it as a command.

Comment: @Kusalananda Aha! Good point. The purpose of the fifo was to execute commands in the reading terminal. As an afterthought, I wanted to also change the cursor shape. Is that not possible in this scenario?

Comment: Since you're wrapping in `sh -c` you need to send the `printf` command itself to the fifo so something like `echo "printf '\e[4 q'" > fifo`

Answer (score 1):

The `sh` is redundant if you intended to send only escape sequences and text via the fifo.  You could do just this:

```
while true; do cat fifo; done
```

Comment: The problem is I mostly want to be able to send runnable commands through the fifo. I was trying to send control sequences in addition to this.